# Difference paths with "\" or "\\"

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

What's the difference between having one bar or two bars? See the two paths below.

"C": "C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe"

C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe

Thanks

Comment: Double backslash (``\\``) is normally a way for represent a **literal** single slash ``\`` in a language, where single slash denotes a **special character**. This is known as **escaping**. If you (re-)read your question post, you will find **no double backslash** in it: this is how *representation* works.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, many thanks for the clarification and make seeing what was under my nose. :) Very much appreciated.